# How to use a character map in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:character-map name="cm">
       <xsl:output-character character="1" string="abc"/>   
       <xsl:output-character character="2" string="def"/>
       <xsl:output-character character="3" string='ghi'/>
    </xsl:character-map>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        123abc
       <abc att="123abc"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="'123abc'"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

No matter how I tried, the character map did not seem to work. Could someone show me how to make it work? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined a character map, but you are not *using* it. Try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:character-map name="cm">
    <xsl:output-character character="1" string="abc"/>   
    <xsl:output-character character="2" string="def"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="3" string='ghi'/>
</xsl:character-map>

<xsl:output use-character-maps="cm" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    123abc
   <abc att="123abc"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="'123abc'"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```